# Neo4j ActiveRecord support using Ruby as interpeter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, jruby, neo4j, ruby-1.9.2

I have a social network built on a relational database using Rails 3.0.7 and **Ruby 1.9.2 as interpreter**. 
 I have to migrate right now to Neo4j, but I read on the documentation that it requires **Jruby as interpreter** because I intend to use the ActiveRecord support (http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/guides/rails3.html) and it's not applicable for me because I already built the whole application using Ruby 1.9.2. 
What do you suggest for me ? Is there any nosql database like Neo4j applicable for Rails 1.9.2 as interpreter ? **Is it difficult to interact with Neo4j renouncing to the ActiveRecord support** ? Tutorials to link and examples are welcome.
Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that neo4j.rb interacts directly with the embedded, high performance neo4j-Java-API, so it requires jruby.

You could look into something similar with [neography](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography) working against the Neo4j-REST server.

Or you use the Neo4j Server - [(J)Ruby extension](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Ruby-script_extension). So you would limit the part of your application that runs in jruby and directly in the Neo4j Server to the persistence layer and then use the exposed REST endpoints in your frontend webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Also, notice with the neo4j server solution you can run a rails frontend on ruby MRI and the backend using neo4j server with the active model compliant neo4j.rb on jruby